# Commands that only affect the local debugger

Tags: windbg, remote-debugging

When doing remote debugging, some commands affect only the local debugger (the debugger on which the command is typed). Examples are:

```
.wtitle
.cls
.browse
.cmdtree
```

At the moment these are all looking like UI related commands. Are there more commands that are only executed on the local debugger?

My research effort:

- I was googling for a list, but maybe the search terms are too common or I don't get them right.
- I have also tried finding a reference in WinDbg help (`.hh`) itself. But the fact is not even documented on the affected commands I found so far.

I am aware that this is asking for a favorite external tools or reference. So if you really think this is off-topic, then vote for close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All debugger processing, including all extension execution, is done in the core debugger process.  So 99+% of commands all need to go to the debugger engine (the initial debugger instance)
The only commands that run only on the remote debugger are indeed a few UI related commands.

I will call out one pair of commands that is interesting on this topic which is the mostly commonly used remote debugger:

`.srcpath` sets the "source code path" in the debugger engine.  This is where the debugger engine will get source information from if it's needed - for example, if a debugger extension wants to get to the source code.

`.lsrcpath` (l - for local) sets the "source code path" in the remote debugger.  This path will be used in windbg (and cdb\kd also) to pull up source files in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Still not a complete list, but many [commands that are not scriptable (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are affected:

```
.lscrfix // works on remote client only
.lsrcpath // works on remote client only
.open 
.write_cmd_hist // writes local history only
.beep
.cls
.hh
.remote // Does not work in WinDbg anyway
```

However, the following ones from the list seem to work:

```
.idle_cmd
.restart
```

Regarding `.write_cmd_hist`: If you want to keep all commands executed during the debug session, it seems good to open a log file (`.logopen`) at the beginning of the session.